# Why the following function is not getting inlined?

Tags: c, inline

Can you please tell me why the following function func1 is not getting inlined?

***Code***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static inline int func1(int a) {
    return a*2;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int value = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);

    value = func1(value);

    printf("value: %d\n", value);

    return 0;
}
```

***Run***

```
$ gcc -Wall -o main main.c
$ objdump -D main | grep func1
0000000000000700 <func1>:
 742:   e8 b9 ff ff ff          callq  700 <func1>
```

Comment: Enable optimization and it probably will inline it.

Comment: ..Probably even without marking it `inline`.

Comment: OT: regarding: `int value = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);`  10 Do not access beyond `argv[0]` with out first checking `argc` to assure the user actually entered the expected number of command line parameters  2) should check the error indication from `strtol()` to assure some number was actually input  3) `strtol()` returns a `long int`, not an `int`

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  The main reason is it is missing the statement: `#include <string.h` to expose the prototype for the function: `strtol()`

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html

Comment: Define function as `static inline int __attribute__((always_inline))func1(int a) {
    return a*2;
}` without any optimize inline func1 and objdump shows nothing

Comment: Enable optimization `gcc -Wall -o main main.c -O3` make func1 inline.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800339/why-didnt-o3-gcc-optimization-inline-this-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is not inlined because one is not doing optimisation, (for debugging, I assume.) From [the GCC online docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html),

> GCC does not inline any functions when not optimizing unless you specify the ‘always_inline’ attribute for the function

Comment: see this about always inline https://stackoverflow.com/a/48212527/7508077

Answer (score 2):

`inline` is literally a mere "suggestion".

Per [**6.7.4 Function specifiers**, paragraph 6 of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.4p6):

> A function declared with an inline function specifier is an inline function. Making a function an inline function suggests that calls to the function be as fast as possible. The extent to which such suggestions are effective is implementation-defined.

As `inline` is just a suggestion, a function with the `inline` specifier may or may not be inlined as the implementation determines.

Comment: yes, I understand it is a suggestion only but what will be inlined if this simple function is not? And what is the reason for that this function is not got inlined?

Comment: @Gábor The function didn't get inlined because the compiler you used, with the options you passed it, didn't inline it.  That's really the only "why" there is.  If you want a function inlined, you have to take care to use a compiler that inlines functions and use it with the arguments necessary to make the inlining you want actually happen.  Barmer got right to the point with the first comment.